# LTI System with Transfer function - Self signal of exponent without complex - question from test

Tags: signal, linear

There is an question from test which drives me nuts.
Let there be LTI system with transfer function H(s).
The impulse response exist:
$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:\left|h\left(t\right)e^{\left(3j+5\right)t}\right|dt<\infty $$
and it has Zero at denominator at s=3-4j
Those information are not related to my question, but it was still given, so I write it anyway.
Now for the problematic question:
Is it possible for an input x(t), there will be output y(t) as:$$x(t)=e^{5t}$$ and $$y(t)=e^{7t}$$

The solution:
There isnt any way, the reason is:
$$y(t) = e^{5t}H(5)\ne e^{7t}$$

My Question:
How did they do the self input, H(5) here? is it wrong? since if I try by definition.
I am stuck because I dont have j, if x(t) was:
$$x(t)=e^{5jt}$$, so it was right, but there isnt j.
Proof:
$$H\left\{e^{5t}\right\}=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }h\left(\lambda \right)\cdot x\left(t-\lambda \right)\:d\lambda =\int _{-\infty \:}^{\infty \:}h\left(\lambda \right)\cdot e^{5\left(t-\lambda \right)}\:d\lambda \:=e^{5t}\int _{-\infty \:\:}^{\infty \:\:}h\left(\lambda \:\right)e^{-5\lambda }d\lambda $$